# Filtering out noise from gpx data

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, noise

I have a Pandas dataframe with column `speed` in which I have occasional noise (data are from a Garmin and represent data captured during a run).

I am trying to find a way to average over adjacent points, but when I hit something like this

```
9.112273445
164.5779550738
84.4553498412
4.231089359
4.3740439706
```

I get caught in an infinite loop.

My algorithm is rather naive:

```
# Get list of indices in which value is great than 6:
idx = z[(z['speed']>=6)].index
while list(idx) != []:
    for i in idx:
        # check if out of bounds
        if i + 1 >= len(z):
            z.iloc[i, z.columns.get_indexer(['speed'])] = (z['speed'].ix[i-2] + z['speed'].ix[i-1])/2
        elif i - 1 < 0:
            z.iloc[i, z.columns.get_indexer(['speed'])] = (z['speed'].ix[i+1] + z['speed'].ix[i+2])/2
        else:
            z.iloc[i, z.columns.get_indexer(['speed'])] = (z['speed'].ix[i-1] + z['speed'].ix[i+1])/2
    idx = z[(z['speed']>=6)].index
```

The problem, of course, is when I have two adjacent values that are very large, this gets stuck in an infinite loop.

I am applying this filter (using a Hanning window) to eliminate random noise: [SciPy Cookbook SignalSmooth](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/SignalSmooth.html?highlight=smooth), but it is not dealing with these large spikes in the data.

Short of discarding them, or setting them to a constant value, is there any other simple method of dealing with them?

***EDIT***

The values I am testing this over are:

```
0           NaN
1      3.508394
2      5.097879
3      7.743824
4      9.138245
5     13.315918
6     12.836310
7     12.001393
8     15.815223
9      0.000000
10    16.622944
11     9.061864
12     2.089729
13     2.710874
Name: speed, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "bridge" values greater than six you can do that like so:

```
import numpy as np

# locate outliers and adjacent values
outliers = np.r_[False, (~np.isfinite(data)) | (data > 6), False]
if np.any(outliers):
    boundaries = np.where(outliers[:-1] != outliers[1:])[0]
    lb = boundaries[::2]
    rb = boundaries[1::2]
    # special case if leftmost and/or rightmost values are outliers 
    lv = data[lb-1]
    if lb[0] == 0:
        lv[0] = data[rb[0]]
    rv = data[rb % len(data)]
    if rb[-1] == len(data):
        rv[-1] = data[lb[-1]-1]
    # create fill values; use a bit of trickery to keep it vectorised
    lengths = rb-lb
    fv = np.repeat((rv-lv)/(lengths+1), lengths)
    sw = np.cumsum(lengths[:-1])
    fv[sw] += fv[sw-1] - rv[:-1] + lv[1:]
    fv[0] += lv[0]
    fv = np.cumsum(fv)
    # place them
    out = data.copy()
    out[outliers[1:-1]] = fv
else:
    out = data.copy()
```

Comment: Running into an issue on `fv = np.repeat((rv-lv)/(lengths+1), lengths)` throwing an error thay
`operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)`

the values are:
`lengths -> [6 2]`
and 
`rv-lv -> 
2     NaN, 9     0.0, 12    NaN` (sorry could not format this as a 3x2 array in comments.)

Comment: So, looks like it is trying to broadcast a 3x2 with a 1x2 array. Not sure what fv represents. Could you please explain.

Comment: @horcle_buzz hm, maybe it's the nans. Also, `rv` and `lv` shouldn't be 2d. Could you give me the input that generates this error?

Comment: @horcle_buzz `fv` stands for fill value it contains all the linear interpolants to replace the outliers.

Comment: Thanks, for confirming. I though `fv` was fill value, and that the operation was giving the array of fill values. Yes, it is the `nan`. I just pasted the chunk I am running this over. I'm trying to do a `fillna`, but skeptical of it working.
So, if I am understanding this correctly, the `rv-lv` operation is doing subtraction by indexed row in the array. The row values I have for `rv` are:
`9     0.000000, 12    2.089729` and `lv` are `2    5.097879, 9    0.000000`, which means that the only common row is index 9. Not sure how to handle index 12 and 2, from `rv` and `lv`, respectively.

Comment: @horcle_buzz I've updated the post, it now handles nans. But I have to admit that I've never worked with pandas, so I do not know what those row indices are good for and how they behave. The code should work if `data` is a 1d numpy array. Does a column with row indices behave like a 1d array?

Comment: According to the documentation, a Series is a "One-dimensional ndarray with axis labels (including time series)" (a single column in a dataframe is a series). I just tried converting the series to an explicit 1d array, since I end up converting it to a list, anyway, and lo' and behold, it worked! Thanks!